# segfault at the end of the main()

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, llvm, clang

I am compiling a program agains LLVM-CLANG. This is the main

```
#include <iostream>

#include "CompilerFactory.h"

#include "clang/Basic/FileManager.h"
#include "clang/Basic/SourceManager.h"
#include "clang/Lex/Preprocessor.h"
#include "clang/Basic/Diagnostic.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
using clang::CompilerInstance;
using clang::TargetOptions;
using clang::TargetInfo;
using clang::FileEntry;
using clang::Token;
using clang::DiagnosticOptions;
using clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter;

CompilerInstance ci;
CSFV::CompilerFactory::GetCompilerInstance(ci);
const FileEntry *pFile = ci.getFileManager().getFile("test.c");
ci.getSourceManager().createMainFileID(pFile);
ci.getPreprocessor().EnterMainSourceFile();
ci.getDiagnosticClient().BeginSourceFile(ci.getLangOpts(),
                                        &ci.getPreprocessor());
Token tok;
do
{
  ci.getPreprocessor().Lex(tok);
  if (ci.getDiagnostics().hasErrorOccurred())
    break;
  ci.getPreprocessor().DumpToken(tok);
  std::cerr << std::endl;
} while (tok.isNot(clang::tok::eof));
ci.getDiagnosticClient().EndSourceFile();
return 0;
}
```

and this is the included class

```
//If they are not defined we have an error at compile time
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

#include "llvm/Support/Host.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/IntrusiveRefCntPtr.h"

#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticOptions.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/TextDiagnosticPrinter.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"
#include "clang/Basic/TargetOptions.h"
#include "clang/Basic/TargetInfo.h"

using namespace clang;

namespace CSFV{

class CompilerFactory
{
public:

  CompilerFactory();

  ~CompilerFactory();

  /// \brief Generate and returns a compiler instance object
  static void GetCompilerInstance(CompilerInstance &ci){
    DiagnosticOptions diagOpts;
    TextDiagnosticPrinter* diagPrinter =
      new TextDiagnosticPrinter(llvm::outs(), &diagOpts, true);
    ci.createDiagnostics(diagPrinter);

    llvm::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<TargetOptions> pto (new TargetOptions());
    pto->Triple = llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();
    TargetInfo *pti =
      TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(ci.getDiagnostics(), pto.getPtr());
    ci.setTarget(pti);

    ci.createFileManager();
    ci.createSourceManager(ci.getFileManager());
    ci.createPreprocessor();
    return;
  }
};
} //end of namespace CSFV
```

For some reason I get a segfault at the end of the execution of the main. What am I missing?

Comment: I dont think I understood your question, but if I run gdb on it I get: 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000042153600 in ?? ()

Comment: Right. That's when you *start* the debugger. Then you start *using* it to find out what went wrong.

Comment: as I said, it returns the segfault after the main returns, I can't debug it.

Comment: Possibly a bug when the destructors run.  Shouldn't `DiagnosticOptions` be allocated on the heap rather than on the stack?

Comment: The strange fact is that if I extract this method and put it into the main, everything works fine...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the same problem I had, but what I did was declare the targetoptions as a new pointer.

eg:

```
clang::TargetOptions *targetOpts=new clang::TargetOptions;
```

I have a feeling targetinfo cleans it up when itself is destroyed.